# Error during convolution of image with a filter in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv c++ .I am getting error with code for convolution (got from internet)which is equivalent to conv2 in matlab. The problem is all the pixel values are becoming 255.The filter which i am using in the code has same size as image. Can anybody please help me in correcting the problem.My opencv c++ code is given below:

```
     #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
     #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<iostream>
     #include<math.h>
     #include<cv.hpp>
     using namespace cv;
     using namespace std;
     Mat gd,img,bimgFiltered,gimgFiltered,rimgFiltered,fin_img;
     Mat b,g,r,cr,cb,cg,B,G,R;
     Mat b_logplane, b_plane,b_logfiltered,b_log,g_logplane,g_plane,g_logfiltered;
     Mat g_log,r_logplane,r_plane,r_logfiltered,r_log;
     Mat kernel, dest;
     int m,n,m1,m2,n1,n2;
     int c = 120;
     double mysum = 0.0, mysum1 = 0.0, k = 0;
     int cent=0,radius=0;
     enum ConvolutionType {   
     /* Return the full convolution, including border */
     CONVOLUTION_FULL, 
     /* Return only the part that corresponds to the original image */
     CONVOLUTION_SAME,
     /* Return only the submatrix containing elements that were not influenced   
     by the border     
     */
      CONVOLUTION_VALID
     };

    void conv2(const Mat &img, const Mat& kernel, ConvolutionType type,Mat& dest)
    {
    Mat source = img;
    if(CONVOLUTION_FULL == type) 
    {
    source = Mat();
    const int additionalRows = kernel.rows - 1, additionalCols = kernel.cols - 1;
    copyMakeBorder(img, source, (additionalRows + 1) / 2, additionalRows / 2, 
        (additionalCols + 1) / 2, additionalCols / 2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
    }

    flip(kernel, kernel, -1);
    Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols / 2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows / 2 - 1);
    int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;
    filter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), kernel, anchor, 0, borderMode);

    if(CONVOLUTION_VALID == type)
    {
    dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols - 1) / 2, dest.cols - kernel.cols /    
    2).rowRange((kernel.rows - 1) / 2, dest.rows - kernel.rows / 2);
    }
    }

    int main()
    {  
    img = imread("milla.bmp",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   
    b.create(img.size(),img.type());
    g.create(img.size(),img.type());
    r.create(img.size(),img.type());

    cr.create(img.size(),img.type());
    cg.create(img.size(),img.type());
    cb.create(img.size(),img.type());

    Mat planes[3];
    split(img,planes);

    bimgFiltered.create(img.size(),img.type());
    gimgFiltered.create(img.size(),img.type());
    rimgFiltered.create(img.size(),img.type());

    dest.create(img.size(), img.type());
    gd.create(img.size(), img.type());

    for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        radius = ((cent - i)^2 + (cent - j)^2);
        gd.at<float>(j, i) = exp((-(radius) / c^2));

        mysum = mysum + gd.at<float>(j, i);
    }
    mysum1 = mysum1 + mysum; 
    }

      k=1/mysum1;
     cout<<endl<<k<<"\n"<<endl;

     for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
       {
        gd.at<float>(j, i) = k * gd.at<float>(j, i);
        }
      } 

     planes[0].convertTo(planes[0],CV_32F,1.0/255.0);
     planes[1].convertTo(planes[1],CV_32F,1.0/255.0);
     planes[2].convertTo(planes[2],CV_32F,1.0/255.0);
     conv2(planes[0],gd,CONVOLUTION_SAME,bimgFiltered);
     conv2(planes[1],gd,CONVOLUTION_SAME,gimgFiltered);
     conv2(planes[2],gd,CONVOLUTION_SAME,rimgFiltered);

     imshow("img",gimgFiltered );
     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with the code:

**Issue 1:**

In the following two lines:

```
radius = ((cent - i)^2 + (cent - j)^2);
gd.at<float>(j, i) = exp((-(radius) / c^2));
```

You are using `^` operator which is the bitwise **XOR** operator in C/C++. I think you are mistaking it for power operator. To take the power of a number you have to use the `pow` function as follows:

```
radius = powf((cent - i),2) + powf((cent - j),2);
gd.at<float>(j, i) = expf((-(radius) / (c*c)));
```

**Issue 2:**

The `gd` matrix is assumed to have floating point values as it is accessed like `gd.at<float>(j, i)`, but it is declared with the same type as that of the image, i.e. `CV_8UC3`. So `gd` should be created as follows:

```
gd.create(img.size(), CV_32FC1);
```

**Issue 3:**

Another possible logical error may be present in the first nested loop. You may have to set `mysum = 0;` before starting the inner loop like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
{
    mysum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        radius = powf((cent - i),2) + powf((cent - j),2);
        gd.at<float>(j, i) = expf((-(radius) / (c*c)));

        mysum = mysum + gd.at<float>(j, i);
    }
    mysum1 = mysum1 + mysum; 
}
```

**Issue 4:**

Output filtered images should be created single channel instead of 3 channels:

```
bimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
gimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
rimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
```

Comment: sir, Thanks for your reply .I tried with all those corrections. Still i am not getting the correct convolution output. I am getting a black image instead.This is the equivalent matlab code.Is that because of some problem in my conversion to opencv c++.     Ir=I(:,:,1);
Ig=I(:,:,2);
Ib=I(:,:,3);
cent = ceil(a/2);
gd = zeros(a,b);
summ=0;
for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        radius = ((cent-i)^2+(cent-j)^2);
        gd(i,j) = exp(-(radius/(c^2)));
    end
end
k=1/(sum(sum(gd)))
F=k .* gd;
F_FIr=conv2(Ir,F,'same');
F_FIg=conv2(F,Ig,'same');
F_FIb=conv2(F,Ib,'same');

Comment: @user2943871... What output are you expecting? Can you post a sample input and output image from the matlab code?

Comment: sorry for the delay sir.

Comment: I don't have 10 reputations to post the images. I am expecting a light gray plane image for any input image but i am getting a full black image.

Comment: @user2943871.. For now, you can upload images on an image hosting website like **imageshack**, and provide the links.